# TypeError: this.http.post(...).map is not a function after update angular 5 to angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I meet some problem  about rxjs6 after update Angular 5 to Angular 6:

```
TypeError: this.http.post(...).map is not a function

error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.

TypeError: rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Observable.of is not a function
```

I have tried some methods , like :

add this import to service.ts

> **import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';**
>
> **change http.post().pipe(map(res => {...}))**

However , all of thoes are not work for me .

My enviroment follow as:

```
 "@angular/cli": "^6.0.3"
 "rxjs": "^6.2.0"
 "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0"
```

**code show as below**
     Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {StorageService} from '../services/storage.service';

@Injectable()
export class VariationService {
ip = environment.url.management;
constructor(private http: HttpClient,
            private storageService: StorageService) { }
getFlowChart(status?) {
    status = status ? status : '';
    let token = this.storageService.getToken('token');
    return this.http.post(
        `${this.ip}/workflow`,
        {
            'access_token': token,
            'type': 'adjustment_workflow_get',
            'data': {
                'status': status
            }
        }
    ).map((res: Response) => {
      if ( res['errcode'] !== '00000') {
        return [];
      }
      return res['datas'];
    });
}
}
```

Another problem typscript file

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadingStrategy, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SelectivePreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
  preloadedModules: string[] = [];
  preload(route: Route, load: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    if (route.data && route.data['preload']) {
      this.preloadedModules.push(route.path);
     return load();
    } else {
      return Observable.of(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you can reproduce the error in a jsfiddle then you will much more likely get an answer.

Comment: ok, I will use jsfiddle again.

Comment: "not work for me" means they are all giving the same error message?

Comment: @Henry  
Exactly，add import { map } from 'rxjs/operators' to service.ts,the teminal not print the error , Howerver, the IDE still show error 'map 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'. '.  Changing http.post().pipe(map(res => {...})) this method really not work all problems.

Comment: Angular6 doesn't need a map operator to deal API data

Comment: @v8-E I have edtor my question that add my code . Can you help me correct my code?

Comment: http://reactive.how/rxjs/pipeable-operators-vs-dot-chaining

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`RxJS v5.5.2+` has moved to **[Pipeable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)** operators to improve tree shaking and make it easier to create custom operators.
 now `operators` need to be  combined using the `pipe` method
**[Refer This](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)**
**New Import**

```
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Example**

```
myObservable
  .pipe(filter(data => data > 8),map(data => data * 2),)
  .subscribe(...);
```

Methods to Create `Observables`

**Previously**

```
 import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
            // or 
            import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of
        const source = Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

            const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

In RXJS:6 syntax has changed and import too Instead of `Observable.of` use `of`

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

    const source = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

**Modified Code**

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {StorageService} from '../services/storage.service';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class VariationService {
ip = environment.url.management;
constructor(private http: HttpClient,
            private storageService: StorageService) { }
getFlowChart(status?) {
    status = status ? status : '';
    let token = this.storageService.getToken('token');
    return this.http.post(
        `${this.ip}/workflow`,
        {
            'access_token': token,
            'type': 'adjustment_workflow_get',
            'data': {
                'status': status
            }
        }
    ).pipe(map((res: Response) => {
      if ( res['errcode'] !== '00000') {
        return [];
      }
      return res['datas'];
    }));
}
}
```

**Modified Code**

```
  import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadingStrategy, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable,of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SelectivePreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
  preloadedModules: string[] = [];
  preload(route: Route, load: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    if (route.data && route.data['preload']) {
      this.preloadedModules.push(route.path);
     return load();
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance! I will try this and tell you result.

Comment: Glad I could Help :) Can you mark it as a correct answer